# R side by side box plot add title at x-axis

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, title, boxplot

I made a side by side box plot by,

```
sidebox <- boxplot(Decreased$Group.1, xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(0,10), at=1)

sidebox <- boxplot(Unchanged$Group.1, add=TRUE, at=3)

sidebox <- boxplot(Increased$Group.1, add=TRUE, at=5)
```

and the results came out like

[image]

My question is how can I add the title for each box plot at the x-axis
like `"Decreased", "Unchanged","Increased"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is making the boxplot all at once and use the `names` argument:

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- list(rlnorm(100), rlnorm(100), rlnorm(100))
boxplot(dat, names = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Error occurs "Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: do you know the other method?

Comment: I have the different rows for each of them